Method to replace pixel color with nearest pixel color that is not itself
For example, say this is the input:

For each pixel in the image, I want to replace that pixel with the color of its closest pixel (in terms of distance) that is not its color.
Here is an example of what I mean:

When thinking of possible ways to do this, I thought of BFS but soon realized that that process would probably take too long as the image size grows. Of course, I could be wrong since I don't have much experience with BFS.
So instead, I am looking to see if there is an alternative process to achieve the same result whether there's some image processing technique to accomplish this or another method.

smells like a distance transform could be a helpful part in the solution. this would work best if your picture contains a moderate number of different colors (palette)

yes, sure you have to go "BFS" there, but it actually means too little in this context. The problem here is that it is an expensive search, requiring you to visit a number of neighbors per pixel that grows quadratically to the "spot size". (remapping each pixel is already a quadratic problem proportional to the image area - so could end having a problem of 4th magnitude if your spots grow along with the image).
This problem requires that you to think about it with no "ready made" standard algorithm, named after someone to be found in books - I would try locating the middle of each spot and spiral away from it - if space the spiral cycles, you will enclose regions that should have the same neighbors.
Or you could trace pixels from selected vertical and horizontal lines, color up entire rectangular regions as long as they have the same color bordering lines, and just go bisecting the distance between these lines, skipping resolved regions.
Also, there are different data you find for a given pixel distances to the spot borders that you could annotate, so that when traversing the image from other pixels, you can reuse that data - but it is not a trivial thing to do.
You will have t think of an approach, and code it up.  (no one here will write code from zero for you. If you happen to have an algorithm that you can't put into code, then you can put all the code you have - that code should be a minimal reproducible example: since it is "Python", include the import statments, file-reading calls to acquire the target image, and call to your function, so that people can tinker with your code and suggest fixes.

A simple BFS implementation would have a worst-case quadratic runtime in the number of pixels, but you can achieve the desired result with linear complexity. Just iterate through all pixels and put pixels with a differently colored neighbor into a queue. Then go through the queue and change the color accordingly and add neighboring pixels of the same color to the end of the queue. You will need a second matrix to remember which pixels have already been added to the queue in order to avoid changing a pixel twice. Once the queue is empty all pixels have been changed.
Note that depending on how you define a neighboring pixel, your resulting "closest pixel" will change: If you are using 4-connected neighbors, each pixel gets changed to the L1 nearest neighbor of different color. If you want L2 nearest neighbors, you will need a priority queue based on distance and increase the size of the neighborhood you are working with in each step.

The use Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned into Stackoverflow. Please, check the Stackoverflow policy about use chat gpt: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1 .

Here's something more "image processing" than the others that latched onto your "BFS" suggestion.
I can suggest two approaches:

assuming a palette of colors
assuming no palette


Given the palette of colors, you'd calculate a mask for each color, then run a distance transform on each of these masks.
This tells you, from any pixel position, the distance to any desired color in the palette.
For some pixel you want to replace, look up its location in all the distance fields, and identify the one that gives the second smallest distance. The first smallest distance is that of its own color, which should be 0. The second smallest distance must necessarily be greater than 0.

I would have loved to demonstrate but your image appears to contain many colors, more than a reasonable palette could fit. I tried editing it but the quantization filter still showed changes when I increased the palette past 30 colors.

Another approach would be to perform this work anew for every pixel you want to alter. Calculate the mask for colors differing from the current pixel. Find the nearest pixel flagged as "true". A distance transform can tell you the distance to it (vastly reducing the search space), and in some implementations, it can even give you the direction to it.
